# How can i print how many times a number repeat inside an array? Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, dom

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Write a JavaScript code that asks the user for a number and then print the number of times that number appears in an array.

I'm doing it with `parseFloat` so I can get the string from the user with a `<input />` and change it to number, then I declared my own array with numbers.

```js
function repeatNumber() {
  const number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number").value);
  const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  let compare = false;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] === number) {
      compare = true;
      count++;
    }
  }

  //compare is my id in a p tag where i'll show the result
  const repeating = document.getElementById("compare");

  repating.textContent = "Is your number in my array ?" + compare;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/controlFlow/script.js"></script>
    <title>Js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="number">Pls place a number to see if it's in my array</label>
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <button onclick="repeatNumber()">Check</button> 
    <p id="compare">  </p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your code there is no attempt at counting occurrences?

Comment: I had a let count=0; and then inside if i place it as count++;. But didn't work :/ so i removed it

Comment: The obvious (though not necessarily "best") way is to iterate over the array, comparing each element to the provided value and counting up the matches.

Comment: It should work. Please replace your code in the question with the version that attempts at counting.

Comment: Perhaps add the HTML as a functional snippet

Comment: Also, the task says "_that asks the user for a number_", are you sure they are not asking for a `prompt()`?

Comment: I added a snippet but no HTML and not sure how you call your function.  "Asking"  did we hear a shout from down the hall? :)

Comment: Tahnk you for your support guys, this is my first question lol i didn't know how to even place the code sorry for that, i've already edited. Well im not using prompt because i'm trying to do it with html, so i'm using  `<input>` and `<p>` to do the job

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```js
function repeatNumber() {

  const number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number").value);
  const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  let compare = false;
  var count = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] === number) {
      count++;
      compare = true;
    }
  }
  const repeating = document.getElementById("compare"); //compare is my id in a p tag where i'll show the result
  repating.textContent = "Is your number in my array ?" + compare;
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and fix the snippet, you shared JavaScript code as HTML.

Comment: There is a nice "Tidy" button/link on the left in the snippet editor to help you format quickly with a single click!

Comment: thanks for your feedback, my apologies this is my first post

Answer (score 0):

```js
function repeatNumber() {
        const numbers = [2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 4, 10, 4];
            const userInput = document.getElementById("number").value;
            const numberToCount = parseInt(userInput);
            if (!isNaN(numberToCount)) {
                const count = numbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                    return currentValue === numberToCount ? accumulator + 1 : accumulator;
                }, 0);

                const resultElement = document.getElementById("compare");
                resultElement.textContent = `Is your number in my array ? ${count} `;
            } else {
                alert("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.");
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/controlFlow/script.js"></script>
    <title>Js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="number">Pls place a number to see if it's in my array</label>
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <button onclick="repeatNumber()">Check</button> 
    <p id="compare">  </p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know that i can use `!isNaN` to compare in this case, i'm kinda new you can tell lol. Thank you.

Comment: Actually isNaN() Function is used to check whether a given value is an illegal number or not. inside the html file input type is the text thats why i checked